# Solving Equations with HeavisideTheta Functions

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerical-value

I need to solve an equation that involves the `HeavisideTheta[]` function, but regardless of the method I use Mathematica returns an error message. For example,

```
NSolve[x*HeavisideTheta[x] == 5, x]
```

returns the message "This system cannot be solved with methods available to NSolve". A similar message occurs with `Solve[]` and `Reduce[]`. Clearly the solution to the equation above is x=5. The full equation I need to solve can only be solved numerically. Are there any alternative functions to solve this equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSolve[x UnitStep[x] == 5, x]
(* {{x -> 5.}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
NMinimize[{1, x*HeavisideTheta[x] == 5}, x]
(*{1., {x -> 5.}}*)
```